# Open top level when at Level 2 menu - Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create an accordion menu for mobile devices in WordPress Woocommerce.
I have tried to use some of the codes in other questions but can't make it happened..

My code can handle only 2 levels...
How can I let the top levels stay open when I press the level 2 of this menu hierarchy?

Thanks!

```js
jQuery('.menu li.menu-item-has-children ').prepend('<span class="span-plus-mobile"><i class="iplus-mobile fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>')

jQuery('.span-plus-mobile').parent().click(function() {
  jQuery(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle(200);
});


jQuery(".span-plus-mobile").click(function() {
 jQuery("i", this).toggleClass("fa-angle-left fa-angle-down");
});
```

```css
  .menu .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="#" role="link">1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
          <a href="#" role="link">2</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="#" role="link">3</a>
              </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#" role="link">3</a>
              </li>
             </ul>
       </ul>
</ul>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="#" role="link">1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
          <a href="#" role="link">2</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="#" role="link">3</a>
              </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#" role="link">3</a>
              </li>
             </ul>
       </ul>
</ul>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="#" role="link">1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
          <a href="#" role="link">2</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="#" role="link">3</a>
              </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#" role="link">3</a>
              </li>
             </ul>
       </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/OEmMaL

Changed you js code based on class to ul li.

```
jQuery('.menu li.menu-item-has-children ').prepend('<span class="span-plus-mobile"><i class="iplus-mobile fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>')

$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).children('ul').toggle();
  $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});

jQuery(".span-plus-mobile").click(function() {
    jQuery("i", this).toggleClass("fa-angle-left fa-angle-down");
});
```